# Server does not let me log in and then kicks me out

Tags: windows-server-2003, roaming-profile

```
Event Type:        Error
Event Source:    Userenv
Event Category:                None
Event ID:              1500
Date:                     5/19/2011
Time:                     1:23:24 PM
User:                     domain\user
Computer:          servername
Description:
Windows cannot log you on because your profile cannot be loaded. Check that you are connected to the network, or that your network is functioning correctly. If this problem persists, contact your network administrator. 
DETAIL - There is not enough space on the disk.
```

Note: Server does not let me log in and then kicks me out! It let's other people log in fine!
The disk is not full, more than 1gb left, a few other people tried logging in without an issue.

Comment: Which drive has (only) 1GB available, the server or the local machine? How big is the profile?

Answer (score 5):

Roaming profiles, eh? The other users' roaming profiles have likely already been loaded, which is why they can log on. Clear out some of that full disk and try again.

Comment: the disk is not full, more than 1gb left, a few other people tried logging in without an issue

Comment: How big is your profile?